# How do I get nested_form to work with Formtastic in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nested-forms, formtastic

I have the following form with Formtastic:

```
= semantic_form_for @user, :url=> url_for(register_path), :html => {:id => "registration_form"} do |f| 

  = f.inputs :name => "Addresses", :id=> "addresses" do
    = f.fields_for :addresses do |a|
      %li.address
        %ol
          = a.input :street
          = a.link_to_remove "Remove address"
    #add_address
      = f.link_to_add "New Address", :addresses
```

I'm getting the following error:

> undefined method `link_to_remove' for #

It doesn't matter if I use `semantic_fields_for` or just `fields_for`

Also, I am using what's on github (which supposedly fixed this) and not the released gem:

```
gem "nested_form", :git => "git://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm pulling my hair out over here :/

Thanks!

**Stack trace**

```
app/views/shared/_address_fields.html.haml:9:in `_app_views_shared__address_fields_html_haml___4308950470074423288_2167792580'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:144:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:55:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:142:in `render'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:256:in `render_partial'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:228:in `block (2 levels) in render'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:33:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:33:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:227:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:22:in `wrap_formats'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:219:in `render'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:41:in `render_partial'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:15:in `render'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:24:in `render'
haml (3.1.4) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:11:in `block in render_with_haml'
haml (3.1.4) lib/haml/helpers.rb:90:in `non_haml'
haml (3.1.4) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:11:in `render_with_haml'
app/views/user/registrations/new.html.haml:17:in `block (3 levels) in _app_views_user_registrations_new_html_haml___2562073157518560036_2193979060'
haml (3.1.4) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:93:in `block in capture_with_haml'
haml (3.1.4) lib/haml/helpers.rb:345:in `call'
haml (3.1.4) lib/haml/helpers.rb:345:in `block in capture_haml'
haml (3.1.4) lib/haml/helpers.rb:569:in `with_haml_buffer'
haml (3.1.4) lib/haml/helpers.rb:341:in `capture_haml'
haml (3.1.4) lib/haml/helpers/xss_mods.rb:61:in `capture_haml_with_haml_xss'
haml (3.1.4) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:93:in `capture_with_haml'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:590:in `fields_for'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1393:in `fields_for_nested_model'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1379:in `block in fields_for_with_nested_attributes'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:91:in `each'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:91:in `method_missing'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1378:in `fields_for_with_nested_attributes'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1261:in `fields_for'
formtastic (2.0.2) lib/formtastic/form_builder.rb:79:in `semantic_fields_for'
app/views/user/registrations/new.html.haml:16:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_user_registrations_new_html_haml___2562073157518560036_2193979060'
haml (3.1.4) lib/haml/helpers.rb:345:in `call'
haml (3.1.4) lib/haml/helpers.rb:345:in `block in capture_haml'
haml (3.1.4) lib/haml/helpers.rb:569:in `with_haml_buffer'
haml (3.1.4) lib/haml/helpers.rb:341:in `capture_haml'
haml (3.1.4) lib/haml/helpers/xss_mods.rb:61:in `capture_haml_with_haml_xss'
formtastic (2.0.2) lib/formtastic/helpers/fieldset_wrapper.rb:34:in `field_set_and_list_wrapping'
formtastic (2.0.2) lib/formtastic/helpers/inputs_helper.rb:292:in `inputs'
app/views/user/registrations/new.html.haml:15:in `block in _app_views_user_registrations_new_html_haml___2562073157518560036_2193979060'
haml (3.1.4) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:181:in `call'
haml (3.1.4) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:181:in `block (2 levels) in form_for_with_haml'
haml (3.1.4) lib/haml/helpers.rb:255:in `with_tabs'
haml (3.1.4) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:181:in `block in form_for_with_haml'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:40:in `block in capture'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:187:in `with_output_buffer'
haml (3.1.4) lib/haml/helpers/xss_mods.rb:109:in `with_output_buffer_with_haml_xss'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:40:in `capture'
haml (3.1.4) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:105:in `capture_with_haml'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:590:in `fields_for'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:373:in `form_for'
haml (3.1.4) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:183:in `form_for_with_haml'
haml (3.1.4) lib/haml/helpers/xss_mods.rb:132:in `form_for_with_haml_xss'
formtastic (2.0.2) lib/formtastic/helpers/form_helper.rb:161:in `block in semantic_form_for'
formtastic (2.0.2) lib/formtastic/helpers/form_helper.rb:192:in `with_custom_field_error_proc'
formtastic (2.0.2) lib/formtastic/helpers/form_helper.rb:160:in `semantic_form_for'
app/views/user/registrations/new.html.haml:6:in `_app_views_user_registrations_new_html_haml___2562073157518560036_2193979060'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:144:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:55:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:142:in `render'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:33:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:33:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:39:in `block in render_template'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:38:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:12:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:22:in `wrap_formats'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:9:in `render'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:250:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:114:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:30:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:43:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:99:in `render'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
/Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:309:in `realtime'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:78:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
devise (1.5.2) lib/devise/controllers/scoped_views.rb:28:in `render_with_scope'
devise (1.5.2) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:9:in `block in new'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:231:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:231:in `default_render'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:160:in `to_html'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:153:in `respond'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:146:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:238:in `respond_with'
devise (1.5.2) lib/devise/controllers/internal_helpers.rb:148:in `respond_with_navigational'
devise (1.5.2) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:9:in `new'
app/controllers/user/registrations_controller.rb:3:in `new'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:434:in `_run__1640754455416320338__process_action__2506477701008906327__callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:386:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:201:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:193:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:41:in `call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `block in call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `block in recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:75:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:95:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:532:in `call'
warden (1.1.0) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.1.0) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.1.0) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.3.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.3.3) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:243:in `call'
rack (1.3.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195:in `context'
rack (1.3.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:331:in `call'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:62:in `call'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:477:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:68:in `call'
rack (1.3.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:101:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.3.3) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.3.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.3.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:456:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/rack/content_length.rb:16:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.3.3) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
```

**Gemfile.lock**

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/haines/nested_form.git
  revision: a0f78ca877a10055f10bd7d9db972432c6be90ae
  specs:
    nested_form (0.1.1)

GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.1.1)
      actionpack (= 3.1.1)
      mail (~> 2.3.0)
    actionpack (3.1.1)
      activemodel (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      rack (~> 1.3.2)
      rack-cache (~> 1.1)
      rack-mount (~> 0.8.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.0.2)
    activemodel (3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
    activerecord (3.1.1)
      activemodel (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      arel (~> 2.2.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.1.1)
      activemodel (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
    activesupport (3.1.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    addressable (2.2.6)
    arel (2.2.1)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    builder (3.0.0)
    cancan (1.6.7)
    cantango (0.9.4.7)
      cancan (>= 1.4)
      hashie (>= 0.4)
      rails (>= 3.0.1)
      sugar-high (>= 0.6.0)
      sweetloader (~> 0.1.0)
    capybara (1.1.2)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      selenium-webdriver (~> 2.0)
      xpath (~> 0.1.4)
    childprocess (0.2.3)
      ffi (~> 1.0.6)
    cocaine (0.2.0)
    coffee-rails (3.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.1.3)
    cucumber (1.1.4)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.2)
      gherkin (~> 2.7.1)
      json (>= 1.4.6)
      term-ansicolor (>= 1.0.6)
    cucumber-rails (1.2.1)
      capybara (>= 1.1.2)
      cucumber (>= 1.1.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.0)
    database_cleaner (0.7.0)
    devise (1.5.2)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.0.3)
      warden (~> 1.1)
    diff-lcs (1.1.3)
    em-websocket (0.3.5)
      addressable (>= 2.1.1)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.9)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (0.12.10)
    execjs (1.2.12)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    factory_girl (2.3.2)
      activesupport
    factory_girl_rails (1.4.0)
      factory_girl (~> 2.3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    ffi (1.0.11)
    formtastic (2.0.2)
      rails (~> 3.0)
    friendly_id (4.0.0.beta14)
    frontend-helpers (0.1.1)
      haml-rails
      rails (~> 3.1.0)
      sass-rails
      sprockets
    geocoder (1.1.0)
    geonames (0.2.2)
    gherkin (2.7.1)
      json (>= 1.4.6)
    growl (1.0.3)
    guard (0.8.8)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    guard-bundler (0.1.3)
      bundler (>= 1.0.0)
      guard (>= 0.2.2)
    guard-cucumber (0.7.4)
      cucumber (>= 0.10)
      guard (>= 0.8.3)
    guard-livereload (0.3.1)
      em-websocket (>= 0.2.0)
      guard (>= 0.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0.3)
    guard-rails (0.0.3)
      guard (>= 0.2.2)
    guard-rspec (0.5.9)
      guard (>= 0.8.4)
    haml (3.1.4)
    haml-rails (0.3.4)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activesupport (~> 3.0)
      haml (~> 3.0)
      railties (~> 3.0)
    hashie (1.2.0)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.0)
    jquery-rails (1.0.19)
      railties (~> 3.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.6.3)
    launchy (2.0.5)
      addressable (~> 2.2.6)
    mail (2.3.0)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.17.2)
    multi_json (1.0.4)
    nokogiri (1.5.0)
    orm_adapter (0.0.5)
    paperclip (2.4.5)
      activerecord (>= 2.3.0)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.2)
      cocaine (>= 0.0.2)
      mime-types
    pg (0.12.0)
      rake-compiler (~> 0.7)
    polyamorous (0.5.0)
      activerecord (~> 3.0)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.3.3)
    rack-cache (1.1)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-mount (0.8.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.1.1)
      actionmailer (= 3.1.1)
      actionpack (= 3.1.1)
      activerecord (= 3.1.1)
      activeresource (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.1.1)
    rails-footnotes (3.7.5)
      rails (>= 3.0.0)
    railties (3.1.1)
      actionpack (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    rake-compiler (0.7.9)
      rake
    rb-fsevent (0.4.3.1)
    rdoc (3.11)
      json (~> 1.4)
    redis (2.2.2)
    redis-store (1.0.0.1)
      redis (~> 2.2.1)
    rest-client (1.6.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    rspec (2.7.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.7.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.7.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.7.0)
    rspec-core (2.7.1)
    rspec-expectations (2.7.0)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.1.2)
    rspec-mocks (2.7.0)
    rspec-rails (2.7.0)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activesupport (~> 3.0)
      railties (~> 3.0)
      rspec (~> 2.7.0)
    rubyzip (0.9.5)
    sass (3.1.11)
    sass-rails (3.1.5)
      actionpack (~> 3.1.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
      sass (~> 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3.2)
    selenium-webdriver (2.15.0)
      childprocess (>= 0.2.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0.9)
      multi_json (~> 1.0.4)
      rubyzip
    sprockets (2.0.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (!= 1.3.0, ~> 1.1)
    sqlite3 (1.3.5)
    squeel (0.9.3)
      activerecord (~> 3.0)
      activesupport (~> 3.0)
      polyamorous (~> 0.5.0)
    sugar-high (0.6.2.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.1)
    sweetloader (0.1.6)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.1)
      i18n
    term-ansicolor (1.0.7)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    transloadit (1.0.2)
      json
      rest-client
    transloadit-rails (1.0.3)
      railties (~> 3)
      transloadit (>= 1.0.2)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.31)
    uglifier (1.1.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.2)
    uuidtools (2.1.2)
    warden (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    xpath (0.1.4)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  cancan
  cantango
  capybara (>= 1.1.1)
  coffee-rails (~> 3.1.1)
  cucumber-rails (>= 1.1.1)
  database_cleaner (>= 0.6.7)
  devise (>= 1.4.7)
  factory_girl_rails (>= 1.2.0)
  formtastic
  friendly_id (~> 4.0.0.beta14)
  frontend-helpers
  geocoder
  geonames
  growl
  guard (>= 0.6.2)
  guard-bundler (>= 0.1.3)
  guard-cucumber (>= 0.6.1)
  guard-livereload (>= 0.3.0)
  guard-rails (>= 0.0.3)
  guard-rspec (>= 0.4.3)
  haml (>= 3.1.2)
  haml-rails (>= 0.3.4)
  jquery-rails
  launchy (>= 2.0.5)
  nested_form!
  paperclip (~> 2.4)
  pg
  rack (= 1.3.3)
  rails (= 3.1.1)
  rails-footnotes (>= 3.7)
  rb-fsevent
  redis
  redis-store
  rspec-rails (>= 2.6.1)
  sass-rails (~> 3.1.4)
  sqlite3
  squeel
  transloadit-rails
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
  uuidtools
```

Comment: Try nested_form gem from this repo `git://github.com/haines/nested_form.git`

Comment: @MikhailNikalyukin I still get the error when I use that address

Comment: I've given up on this and I'm moving to https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon but I'll leave this question open and award the bounty to someone that answers. Others will likely need this answered in the future until it's resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change `semantic_form_for` to `semantic_nested_form_for` - like described in the [readme](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) under "formtastic support"